# Ubuntu apt-get update connecting to 10.8.0.1

Tags: 14.04, apt, openvpn

I am trying to run the command `sudo apt-get update` on Ubuntu 14. It is trying to connect to `10.8.0.1` and failing.

`npm install` is also failing for the same reason. I found that `10.8.0.1` is associated with `openvpn`. I have installed `openvpn` on this system.

Here is the output of the command:

```
Err http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net trusty InRelease                             
Err http ://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb InRelease                          
Err http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net trusty-updates InRelease                     
Err http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net trusty-backports InRelease                   
Err http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net trusty-security InRelease                    
Err http ://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb Release.gpg                        
  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
Err http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net trusty Release.gpg                           
  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
Err http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net trusty-updates Release.gpg                   
  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
Err http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net trusty-backports Release.gpg                 
  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
Err http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net trusty-security Release.gpg                  
  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
Err http ://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Err http ://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Err http ://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Err http ://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Err http ://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Err http ://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Err http ://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
Err http ://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
Err http ://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
Err http ://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
Err http ://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
Err http ://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
Err http ://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Err http ://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Err http ://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
Err http ://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                           
  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
Err http ://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist InRelease                    
Err http ://downloads-distro.mongodb.org dist Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http ://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http ://ppa.launchpad.net/fantasyleague0629/wildguppy/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http ://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-2/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http ://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http ://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http ://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http ://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http ://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http ://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http ://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http ://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http ://ppa.launchpad.net/fantasyleague0629/wildguppy/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http ://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-2/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http ://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http ://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http ://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http ://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http ://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http ://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
W: Failed to fetch http ://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.8.0.1:8080:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Please restructure your question its a bit confusing, what is going where ? What are you trying to update that is going to `10.8.0.1`.

Comment: can you please provide the output of `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: I added a space after http because it requires more than 10 reputation points to add more than 2 links in post.

Comment: You should use code formatting (ctrl-k), note quote formatting (ctrl-q). That will show the output exactly as it should be, and you don't have to worry about links.

Comment: What's the output of `host ppa.launchpad.net` as opposed to `host ppa.launchpad.net 8.8.8.8`? What's the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` and the output of `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX nm-tool`?

Answer (score 0):

You may have something like

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://10.8.0.1:8080/";
```

in your `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file. Just remove this line. It should work.